# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Синтаксическая ошибка в выражении SQL

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, h2

Использую базу данных H2 и mode к ней MySQL.

Есть запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE `warps` (
  `id`             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL         AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`           varchar(32)         NOT NULL,
  `creator`        varchar(32)         NOT NULL,
  `world`          varchar(32)         NOT NULL,
  `welcomeMessage` varchar(100)        NOT NULL,
  `position`       TEXT                NOT NULL,
  `invitedPlayers` TEXT                NOT NULL,
  `blacklist`      TEXT                NOT NULL,
  `publicAll`      boolean             NOT NULL,
  `visits`         int                 NOT NULL         DEFAULT 0
);
```

Есть код который его выполняет:

```
    private void checkTable() {
        this.connection = this.getConnection();
        try (PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY)) {
            ps.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            this.logger.error("Error creating/check table in database.", ex);
        }
    }

private Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        if ((this.connection == null) || (this.connection.isClosed())) {
            reconnect();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return this.connection;
}

private void reconnect() throws SQLException {
    if (this.connection != null) {
        this.connection.close();
    }
    this.connection = this.openConnection();
}

private Connection openConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2://" + this.plugin.getConfDir().toString() + File.separatorChar + "warps" + ";mode=MySQL", "User", "");
}
```

В итоге я получаю ошибку:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Синтаксическая ошибка в выражении SQL "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ""WARPS"" (""ID"" INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT[*], ""NAME"" VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, ""CREATOR"" VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, ""WORLD"" VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, ""WELCOMEMESSAGE"" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, ""POSITION"" TEXT NOT NULL, ""INVITEDPLAYERS"" TEXT NOT NULL, ""BLACKLIST"" TEXT NOT NULL, ""PUBLICALL"" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,""VISITS"" INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0); "; ожидалось "CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ""WARPS"" (""ID"" INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT[*], ""NAME"" VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, ""CREATOR"" VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, ""WORLD"" VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, ""WELCOMEMESSAGE"" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, ""POSITION"" TEXT NOT NULL, ""INVITEDPLAYERS"" TEXT NOT NULL, ""BLACKLIST"" TEXT NOT NULL, ""PUBLICALL"" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,""VISITS"" INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0); "; expected "CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `warps` (`id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `creator` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `world` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `welcomeMessage` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `position` TEXT NOT NULL, `invitedPlayers` TEXT NOT NULL, `blacklist` TEXT NOT NULL, `publicAll` boolean NOT NULL,`visits` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0); [42001-196]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте порядок атрибутов поменять. Например

```
`id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую, пока что оставил так: ```\`id` INT PRIMARY KEY``` и всё работает...

Comment: В H2 похоже есть небольшой баг из-за которого важен порядок атрибутов столбца.

Comment: Капец, а главное в гугле ваще инфы нет по этому поводу. Час сидел не мог понять в чём причина.

Comment: Теперь будет :)